# const string doesnt work if appended at the end

Tags: c++, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Concatenate two string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061648/concatenate-two-string-literals)

Why doesn't this work ?

```
const std::string exclam = "!";          
const std::string message = "Hello" + ", world" + exclam;
```

BUT this works fine

```
const std::string exclam = "!";       
const std::string message = exclam +
"Hello" + ", world" ;
```

Please explain to me.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/13507/

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that there is no `operator+` for adding two string literals, and it is not needed. Your first example works if you just *remove* the `+`.

```
const std::string message = "Hello"  ", world" + exclam;
```

because <strike>preprocessor</strike> compiler magic*) will add the two adjacent literals together.

The second example works because `std::string` does have an `operator+` that adds a string literal. The result is another string, that can concatenate the next literal.

---

*) Translation phase 6 - *Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated.*

Comment: nitpick, string concatenation isn't actually done by the preprocessor, (which means it doesn't have to be avoided the way we avoid the preprocessor ;)

Comment: Ok, make that *compiler* magic.

Answer (score 3):

Because expression `"Hello" + ", world"` doesn't involve any `std::string`, but two `const char[]` arguments. And there is no operator+ with that signature. You have to convert one of those to `std::string` first:

```
const std::string message = std::string("Hello") + ", world" + exclam;
```

Comment: This would work, too: `const std::string message = "Hello" + (", world" + exclam);`

Answer (score 1):

std::string has a + operator which is what is being used in the second example.
const char * does not have that operator, which is being used in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

It's down to associativity.

The second case begins (from the left) evaluation with `std::string` which is concatenated with `operator+`. The first case begins with `const char *` and no concatenation `operator+` exists for that.

Comment: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/31-precedence-and-associativity/

Answer (score 0):

The "const string doesn't work if appended at the end" is a red herring. This doesn't work, either:

```
const std::string message = "Hello" + ", world";
```

The reason this doesn't work has been explained in the other answers.