# c++ change directory of ofstream with a string buffer filename

Tags: c++, directory, ofstream

I have this line of code

```
    std::ofstream output(p_strFilename.c_str());
```

where `p_strFilename` is defined from a function parameter

```
    foo(const std::string &p_strFilename)
```

which is saving a bunch of files in the current working directory. However I want to enter a step inside that directory and save the files inside. I tried

```
    std::ofstream output("folder1\\"+p_strFilename.c_str())
```

this is giving me

```
    error: invalid operands of types ‘const char [9]’ and ‘const char*’ to binary ‘operator+’
```

which I guess is reading the directory as 9 characters instead of as a string.

First question: Is that the right way to input a directory? (double backslash and starting from the CWD not form home directory)

Second question: How can I resolve my compilation error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to convert to c_string only after the concatenation:

```
std::ofstream output(("folder1/"+p_strFilename).c_str())
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: @RawN it should if:
1. p_strFilename is of type std::string and
2. output() takes a "const char *" as parameter.

Why do you think it will not compile?

Comment: @RawN If p_strFilename is of type "const char*", how can it be that
    p_strFilename.c_str()
works? I thought that c_str() was a method of the std::string type...

Comment: although this removed my compilation error, what is happening now is that the files are still being save in the cwd with the name "folder1\file1.txt", "folder1\file2.txt", etc.. how can i solve this

Comment: +p_strFilename is not of type char* its of type std::string already.. i edited the question

Comment: @j.doe could you try with a "slash" instead of a "backslash"? I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: you don't need .c_str() ofstream constructor accepts string in c++11

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `.c_str()`.

The `operator+` don't work with two `char*`, you must use `std::string` `operator+` to add strings like this.

```
std::ofstream output("folder1\\"+p_strFilename);
```

> [(One of the two strings being concatenated must be a std::string
>   object)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061648/concatenate-two-string-literals)

Comment: @j.doe, don't you use c_str(), this give you a const char*, but you need a std::string to add the literal string "folder1\\"