# neo4j-client in C, raw type encoding in a statement (i.e. int)

Tags: c++, c, neo4j, cypher, libneo4j-client

How can I send a statement with an integer type in neo4j-client? Fore example, in `CREATE (n:Node {id:1})` the value of the field id is 1. Also, how can I retrieve it?

I have tried, assuming:

```
std::stringstream ss;
neo4j_run(connection,
            ss.str().c_str(), neo4j_null);
```

--

```
ss << "RETURN 'hello world'"; // server returns 'hello world'
ss << "RETURN 1"; // server returns 1
ss << "CREATE (n:Node {id:" << std::to_string(2) << "}); // Statement failed
ss << "CREATE (n:Node {id:" << neo4j_int(2) << "})"; // compile error
```

I am also printing those strings in the console, and `CREATE (n:Node {id:" << std::to_string(2) << "})` copy-pasted fro the consolo to the web gui works.

Comment: What have you tried so far? The [docs](https://neo4j-client.net/) show this line for running a query: `neo4j_result_stream_t *results = neo4j_run(connection, "RETURN 'hello world'", neo4j_null);` -- what happens if you run your query this way?

Comment: @GaborSzarnyas I have added what I have tried.

Comment: My C++ is a little rusty, but I'm pretty sure you do not concatenate strings with the `<<` operator, which only works for output streams. Try something along the lines of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061648/concatenate-two-string-literals.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably best sending the integer ID as a parameter, e.g.:

```
neo4j_map_entry_t map_entry = neo4j_map_entry("id", 2);
neo4j_value_t params = neo4j_map(&map_entry, 1);
neo4j_run(session, "CREATE (n:Node {id:$id});", params);
```