# Problems with adding string and literals in C++

Tags: c++, string, c++11, literals

In the definition of `s6` and `s7`, how is there a string for every + in `s6` and how come it's not still so in `s7`?

```
#include <string>
using std::string;
int main()
{
string s1 = "hello", s2 = "world";
string s3 = s1 + ", " + s2 + '\n';
string s4 = s1 + ", "; // ok: adding a string and a literal
string s5 = "hello" + ", "; // error: no string operand
string s6 = s1 + ", " + "world"; // ok: each + has a string operand
string s7 = "hello" + ", " + s2; // error: can't add string literal
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[expr.add]p1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#1):

> The additive operators + and - group left-to-right. [...]

`+` and `-` are left associative, that means that actually, the last two definitions look like this:

```
string s6 = (s1 + ", ") + "world";
string s7 = ("hello" + ", ") + s2;
```

Now the error is obvious: `"hello" + ", "` is evaluated first, but because  there is no addition operator for `const char[]`, you get a compiler error. If the operators were right associative, `s7` would be valid, while `s6` would not.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the + operator having left to right associativity.

Find a better description of this here:
[Concatenate two string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061648/concatenate-two-string-literals)

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between the notion of a "string literal" such as `"hello"` and `", "` and a "`std::string` object".

String literals are just `char[]` and adding two to each other doesn't have the effect you think it has. You're just adding the two pointers, which doesn't amount to anything meaningful in your case.

On the other hand, the `operator+()` method is defined on operands `std::string` and `char*` such that it returns a `std::string` object. This is when the other concept you are missing comes into play: operator associativity. In the case of the following line:

```
string s6 = s1 + ", " + "world";
```

1. `s1 + ", "` returns a `std::string`
2. That returned object is concatenated to `"world"`, also returning a `std::string` object. This works as expected

On the other hand, the following statement:

```
string s7 = "hello" + ", " + s2;
```

Does not work as expected because the first part of the expression being evaluated is `"hello" + ", "`, which is an attempt to add 2 string literals.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add string literals `"hello" ", "` will be glued by preprocessor to `"hello, "`.