# Adding strings and literals, how does the order affect if you can add the strings without error

Tags: c++, string, string-literals

Consider the following string definitions:

```
string s1 = "hello", s2 = "world";
string s6 = s1 + ", " + "world";
string s7 = "hello" + ", " + s2;
```

The book C++ Primer 5e states that the third line will cause the compiler to give an error because you cannot add string literals. The actual error given from the compiler is

```
error: invalid operands of types 'const char [6]'
and 'const char [3]' to binary 'operator+'
```

But isn't the second string `s6` doing the exact same thing as `s7`? What is the difference?

Comment: Duplicate of [Concatenate two string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061648/concatenate-two-string-literals), including discussion of left-associativity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since addition associates left-to-right, `s6` is parsed as `(s1 + ", ") + "world"`.  This adds a `string` to a `const char *`, resulting in another `string`.  Then we add another `const char *` to that `string`, resulting in a third `string` that is stored in `s6`.

`s7` is parsed as `("hello" + ", ") + s2`, which tries to add a `const char *` to another `const char *`, which you can't do.  You could rewrite it as `"hello" + (", " + s2)` and it would then compile.